# Include a file in Ansible and have it perform 2 or more actions based on when condition

Tags: include, ansible, action, conditional-statements

Trying to include a file called Agent-install.yml
and based on first 2 characters of the hosts name (example: dserver or qserver or userver or pserver)
want to use sed update the agent.properties.j2 to the appropriate value...

i.e if the host name start with ds/qs/us then agent.setup.IP=DevMaster1
otherwise if hostname starts with ps then agent.setup.IP=ProdMaster1

in either case they should both include Agent-install.yml 
(BTW I'm passing the hosts name during playbook run and it does work 
(just not with 2 actions) sed portion is what I'm trying to add here

Anyone have Ideas on how to do this?
I've tried having 2 actions using when condition (but don't think that is allowed)
Also tried -block which does allow multiple actions but does not allow include

Is there a better way to do this?

```
- name: Include if Pre-PROD
  include: Agent-install.yml
  local_action: shell sed -i 's@.*agent.setup.IP=localhost.*@agent.setup.IP=DevMaster1@' ../templates/agent.properties.j2
  when: hosts[0:2] == "ds" or "qs" or "us"
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Include if PROD
  include: Agent-install.yml
  local_action: shell sed -i 's@.*agent.setup.IP=localhost.*@agent.setup.IP=ProdMaster1@' ../templates/agent.properties.j2
  when: hosts[0:2] == "ps"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're on the wrong path...

Templates are used to generate different result files, based on input data.
You are not supposed to `sed` templates locally.

Modify your `agent.properties.j2` template to have:

```
agent.setup.IP={{ agent_ip }}
```

Then in your playbook:

```
- set_fact:
    agent_ip: "{{ 'ProdMaster1' if hosts[0:2] == 'ps' else 'DevMaster1' }}"

- template:
    src: agent.properties.j2
    dest: agent.properties.conf
```

This way `agent.properties.conf` at target host will have appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks
getting this error for set_fact

 FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u\"'\" at 44. String:

Comment: There was a typo in a single quote after DevMaster1

Comment: Works perfectly, this is definitely a better solution!